# Android and c# tcp communication

Tags: c#, android, tcp

I want to send a message from a C# application to the Android emulator or device over TCP. I have searched on Google and got the maximum results for Android client and C# server but not what I want to acheive.

Here is what I have tried; maybe I am going about it the wrong way but what I want is to send a message over TCP to an Android device.

Server Code to send a message:

```
    private static int port = 4444;
    private static TcpListener listener;
    private static Thread thread;
    private static int clientId = 0;

  listener = new TcpListener(new IPAddress(new byte[] { 127, 0, 0, 1 }), port);
        thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Listen));
        thread.Start();

private static void Listen()
    {
        listener.Start();
        MessageBox.Show("Listening on: " + port.ToString());

        while (true)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Waiting for connection....");
            MessageBox.Show("Client No: " + clientId);
            TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient();
            Thread listenThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(ListenThread));
            listenThread.Start(client);
        }
    }

    private static void ListenThread(Object client)
    {

        NetworkStream netstream = ((TcpClient)client).GetStream();
        MessageBox.Show("Request made");
        clientId = clientId + 1;
        // String message = "Hello world";
        byte[] resMessage = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(clientId.ToString());
        netstream.Write(resMessage, 0, resMessage.Length);
        netstream.Close();
    }
```

Client Code

```
private TextView textDisplay;
Socket socket;
private static final int TCP_SERVER_PORT = 4444;
ServerSocket ss = null;
    try {
        ss = new ServerSocket(TCP_SERVER_PORT);
        //ss.setSoTimeout(10000);
        //accept connections
        Socket s = ss.accept();
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(s.getOutputStream()));
        //receive a message
        String incomingMsg = in.readLine() + System.getProperty("line.separator");
        Log.d("TcpServer", "received: " + incomingMsg);
        textDisplay.append("received: " + incomingMsg);
        //send a message
        String outgoingMsg = "goodbye from port " + TCP_SERVER_PORT + System.getProperty("line.separator");
        out.write(outgoingMsg);
        out.flush();
        Log.d("TcpServer", "sent: " + outgoingMsg);
        textDisplay.append("sent: " + outgoingMsg);
        //SystemClock.sleep(5000);
        s.close();
    } catch (InterruptedIOException e) {
        //if timeout occurs
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (ss != null) {
            try {
                ss.close();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                Log.d("Error",e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Both your client and server open a server socket and wait for connections. Your client should connect to the server instead of opening a `ServerSocket`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies in your `Client` code.
A socket is opened between two parties, one that plays the role of the listener / server that does `bind->listen->accept` and a client that `connect`
In your code there are two problems:

1. Your client should `connect` and not `accept`
2. Both your client and your server will try to read from the socket and write afterwards. There would be no problem if your read and write operations from the socket were on different threads.In your case this will result in a deadlock.
   If you want both operations to be done on the same thread , sequentially then your client and server should perform the read and write in opposite order :
   Client : `read -> write` 
   Server:  `write-> read`